# Do the 5.x versions of Microsoft.Extensions.* nuget packages require .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, asp.net-core-5.0

You've got package updates! Or do you?

Are all those new 5.x packages (Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, et al) dependent on .NET 5.0 framework or do they gracefully degrade or expose feature subsets when used in a NetCoreApp3.1 or (dog forbid) NetStandard 2.0?

I'm thinking the latter as they list dependencies for earlier frameworks and I've installed them accidentally in "lesser" projects, but I'd love to know just what the 5.0 represents.

Thanks!

Comment: Check the packages on fuget.org

Comment: Here's the fuget for Microsoft.Extensions.Logging: http://fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging